# Queries from jdbc request does not pass to the DB while validation query do pass, what to do?

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I am trying to work with the JMeter test tool with a JDBC connector to my DB. I opened a group of threads and JDBC connection configuration and JDBC request.

When I ran the test it didn't give me any result in "view result tree" and it didn't send the queries to my DB but when I look into my logs in my DB I saw that the validation query "`select 1`" do pass, so I guess the connection is good but there is a problem in the queries that I send from the page of "jdbc request"

I get the following error `Error while processing sampler: 'JDBC Request'.`
 help anyone?

log:

```
2019-01-31 10:27:51,840 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-01-31 10:27:51,848 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-01-31 10:27:51,849 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-01-31 10:27:52,012 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-01-31 10:27:52,012 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-01-31 10:27:52,012 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-01-31 10:27:52,012 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2019-01-31 10:27:52,012 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-01-31 10:27:52,012 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-01-31 10:27:52,013 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-01-31 10:27:52,218 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'JDBC Request'.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
2019-01-31 10:27:52,219 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-01-31 10:27:52,219 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-01-31 10:27:52,219 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-01-31 10:27:52,224 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: Could you provide more logs? Any information after "Error while processing sampler: 'JDBC Request'." the log?

Comment: its part of it. the system wont allow me to post more than that (i meand that stackoverflow are limiting comment size)

Comment: You may add logs to your first question post actually

Comment: And could you include responce data of your JDBC sampler?

Comment: what do u mean with responce data?

Comment: If you add View Result Tree listener, when you will see that JDBC Sampler in the tree. Choose it and select tab Responce data.

Comment: I think it shows ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'JDBC Request'. java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: What is your JMeter version?

Comment: And what DataBase do you use?

Comment: DB is SQream and the version of Apach is 5.0 the most strange thing is that the validation query do pass so i guess the jdbc connection is working

Answer (score 0):

Update your JDBC Driver. For Postgress [current version is 42.2.5](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html). Download, copy to `JMeter\lib` dir and restart JMeter.